# No connection to WG household_object_database

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the guide on the wiki. I have installed the database on my desktop, which works fine. However, on the robot I would like to access the database remotely.
I launch with

**$ roslaunch household_objects_database objects_database_remote_client.launch**

which seems fine. However, when calling one of the remapped services, I get return code 3. I've tried both **ping grasp.willowgarage.com** and **telnet grasp.willowgarage.com 15432** which also work fine, so I guess it's not a network problem.

The same error occurs on both the robot and my desktop.

The issue is very similar (i.e. identical) to [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/9245/household_objects_database-returns-3-query-error/).

**UPDATE:** I tried it from my home network as well, and there is still no connection, and still replies with error code 3. I'm surprised no one knows how to fix this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40671/no-connection-to-wg-household_object_database/) by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
for the issues like this I'd normally drop an email to Matei (http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/people/matei-ciocarlie) to restart the server at Willow.
D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-09-10**:
marking this as the right answer, and hope it will not result in Matei getting spammed

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-09-10**:
oh, and obviously I did indeed write to Matei, and he did fix it

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2012-11-30**:
Unfortunately, we are likely to discontinue support for this, as it proved to be a bit of a headache to keep the ROS wrapper up on this side...

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2012-11-30**:
I encourage everybody to set up their local server, it is really not that complicated and the tutorial in the household_objects_database package provides step-by-step instructions.